# Add SQS Trigger to Lambda Using SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services

I know how to add an SQS trigger to Lambda using the console, but is there a way to programmatically do this? I am expecting to use a lambda SDK for .net.

Comment: what do you mean by sqs trigger to lambda? do you need to publish messages to SQS through a lambda function or else do you need to trigger a lambda when a message hits to the queue?

Comment: I need to trigger lambda when the message hits the queue.

Comment: you should do that using cloudformation or else from the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you would add this trigger using [AWS Cloudformation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) script.

Specifically you can use [AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-eventsourcemapping.html) for doing that.

Following is the sample template that is provided in the above page.

```
"EventSourceMapping": {  
  "Type": "AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping",
  "Properties": {
    "EventSourceArn" : { "Fn::Join" : [ "", [ "arn:aws:kinesis:", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, ":", { "Ref" : "AWS::AccountId" }, ":stream/", { "Ref" : "KinesisStream" }] ] },
    "FunctionName" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : ["LambdaFunction", "Arn"] },
    "StartingPosition" : "TRIM_HORIZON"
  }
}
```

Comment: I see, hmm I was expecting something like lambdaClient.AddTrigger(SqsARN)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use Cloudformation. You can use the lambda class from aws sdk.

```
    var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();
    var params = {
       BatchSize: 5, 
       EventSourceArn: "arn:aws:sqs:us-west-2:123456789012:my-queue", 
       FunctionName: "my-function"
    };
    lambda.createEventSourceMapping(params, function(err, data) {
       if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
       else     console.log(data);           // successful response
    };
```